# While retriving data for mutiple AJAX call with 2 different methods using DataReader

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

While retriving data for mutiple AJAX call with 2 different methods using DataReader.

method 1:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = clientDb.ExecuteSPReader("SP1", 
                                        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection,
                                        parameters))
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

method 2:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = clientDb.ExecuteSPReader("SP2", 
                                        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection,
                                        parameters))
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

both the method is execute on a single db. Should it suggested that I would not close the reader, as It will be closed by GC? and I am executing reader with "using" statement.

In my case, issue is as both the method is using same database. One method

```
reader.close()
```

closes the other method connection and it jumps to exception. So, wanted to know what is the best way to implement such a AJAX request methods.

I have also read in following url that one should not close or dispose the managed objects.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, by using the `using` statement, when the execution leaves the scope, SqlDataReader will be disposed. It is the same as calling `reader.Dispose()` manually.

Since the reader don't have a dependency on external or un-managed code, like your `SqlConnection`, you don't have to dispose it but you should always [close it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx). The disposal will be managed by the GC.

Further on you should really wrap your `SqlConnection` in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx), since it's using a connection pool to the database. And it is not very good for performance if you leave a lot of open connections to the database, when they are not in use.

I assume these database calls are made in two different calls to the server, and not in sequence just after each other in the same method.